# TypeScript, how to type function that converts Promise<T>[] to Promise<T[]>?

Tags: typescript

suppose I have some function like:

```
function allPromises<T>(array: Promise<T>[]): Promise<T[]> {
  return Promise.all(array);
}
```

(note: this is intentionally contrived to be minimally reproducible)

If I did this, it works fine:

```
const p1: Promise<string> = new Promise((resolve) => resolve('1'));
const p2: Promise<string> = new Promise((resolve) => resolve('2'));
const test1 = [p1, p2];
const res1 = allPromises(test1);
```

no type errors and `res1` is properly typed as `Promise<string[]>`;

but if I do:

```
const p1: Promise<string> = new Promise((resolve) => resolve('1'));
const p2: Promise<number> = new Promise((resolve) => resolve(2));
const test2 = [p1, p2];
const res2 = allPromises(test2);
```

now I get a TS complaint that:

> Argument of type '(Promise<string> | Promise<number>)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<string>[]'.

It seems to be because `test2` is typed as `(Promise<number> | Promise<string>)[]`

I can fix this by doing:

```
const test2: Promise<string | number>[] = [p1, p2];
```

then `res2` is typed properly as `Promise<(string | number)[]>`

but is there a way to type my function so that it can infer the type properly and not force me to declare the type of the array explicitly in this way?

Note: I also tried overloading the function similar to how the `Promise.all` typing is done, but it also failed and required me to explicitly type the array for TS to accept it:

```
function allPromises<T1, T2>(array: [Promise<T1>, Promise<T2>]): Promise<[T1, T2]>
function allPromises<T>(array: Promise<T>[]): Promise<T[]>
function allPromises(array: Promise<unknown>[]): Promise<unknown[]> {
  return Promise.all(array);
}
```

and this overload also didn't help:

```
function allPromises<T1, T2>(array: (Promise<T1> | Promise<T2>)[]): Promise<(T1 | T2)[]>
```

and I'm looking to make this work in TS V3 ... I see some new types in V4.5+ can be useful for this, but I am stuck in V3 for the time being.

Comment: What is the expected type for `res2`?

Comment: @Bergi `Promise<(string | number)[]>` is what I'm after here.

Comment: and probably worth mentioning that I'm looking for a fix that works in TS V3.X.X ... I see some new types in 4.5 may be helpful in solving this problem but that's out of reach for me atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work with

```
type UnwrapPromiseArr<T> = T extends Promise<infer R>[]
  ? Promise<R[]>
  : never;

function allPromises<T extends Promise<unknown>[]>(array: T): UnwrapPromiseArr<T> {
  return Promise.all(array) as UnwrapPromiseArr<T>;
}
```

They key is to infer the union types that initially come from the inner Array.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgdwE4EMwAUkHsC2BLAZwgEEkkAeAFQD4oBeKSqCAD2AjgBMCpNdCI5PHABmEJFABK1ANoBdAFBQoAfl7Z8RcpPnUlUAFxQ4EAG7iA3AoUiArnADGwPFjhQUAGw99NEAlWY2Dm51fi0UOBBZOWoAChQyFBAjSgBKI3hkNB8BUgoaKABvfSQIYFskNxyiADpPD3jEkFT3HgiQKwBfawdXAmAoMABGI2rBfqRhAHNaBhMEUN9Y2NKCLA9zFrpaVfXzWIByIYPU1KteuH7BgCZRjQFyCenZ4wgFseXdjYgtnb89iCHa4nM4KC5Xdj9Ib0KAyYYAGhucnOfQGq2hDHqYwIsUhwCGoLBqMGAGY7mFxsBJnAZjD5osBJ9-t9flAvvsjiCUZcBmAACzk3zkOC2HAAI3EL3pHxWzM29D%20a2%20sWup25EL8wGuMLhJMR-ORRJ5bL82sxXmxuM1qqsQA)

Comment: nice. thanks a lot. made a minor edit to not use `any` but works great

Answer (score 1):

Your function is just doing the same thing as `Promise.all`, so just define it as an alias and defer the great typing to the original function's:

```
const allPromises = Promise.all;

const p1: Promise<string> = new Promise((resolve) => resolve('1'));
const p2: Promise<number> = new Promise((resolve) => resolve(2));
const test2 = [p1, p2];
const res2 = allPromises(test2);
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwQBQE4gLYEsIFMIwC8MamOuAdIggNwBQdoksADgIwBcJ62eAPNFRYwAcwB8RGGFwB3bmTwAKRanwgEAN1wBKIhNUR1WxQHI2J7dvpNoMFgCYupXrj5gArhgBGuVBOLScs7kygZGOnowYZq4ivaW1uC2UPhQ9pIA2uwANHb2ALqJzFH46cTUwXgQiinQ8TRAA)

Comment: the example here is intentionally contrived to be minimally reproducible. this is not what I'm actually trying to do.

Comment: also worth noting that this only even started working in TS V4.5 ... Ideally I'm looking for a fix that works in TS V3.x.x